# How to fix pip error "Error while finding module specification for 'pip' (AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__')"?

Tags: python, pip

In a virtual environment I get the error

```
path/to/python: Error while finding module specification for 'pip' (AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__')
```

when I run commands like

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip freeze
```

However, when I run the same command with `pip` it works, e.g.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip freeze
```

`python` is the same as `python3`, version is 3.8.12, I reinstalled pip using

```
pip install --force-reinstall pip
```

pip version is 21.3.1.

What else can I do so the `python -m pip` commands work again?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that a version 60.3.0 is being used, which has a bug. But you cannot install a different version of `setuptools`, because you have already installed version 60.3.0.

Solution: Wait for version >60.3.0

On 7 Jan 2022 Version 60.3.1 has been released, which fixed the problem in the question.